# Matching friends in groups

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I want to split a group of people into subgroups. Each person has given me a list of at most 3 preferences of people they want to be in a group together with.
Some people have given a list of fewer than 3 preferences, and some have none.

Constraints on subgroups are:

- Size of subgroup (max 40; as close to 40 as possible, so not groups of fewer than 25)
- Gender balance in subgroup (as close to balanced as possible)

Constraints on members are:

- I want to guarantee that each person is with at least 2 of their preferences.

I have been reading up on bipartite graph assignment problems, but I'm not sure if this problem is related.
I don't think I can brute-force the problem, as the largest group is 450 people.

Comment: The constraints on the subgroup only leave (by Lagrange), that the subgroup has $25$ or $30$ members. But yes, my idea of a subgroup is different from yours :)

Comment: Generally speaking the task is not solvable - if everybody lists the same two people you are at a dead end. Practically I have found that in a lot of real life situations just going the "naive" way tends to produce great results. In a problem like yours I'd decide beforehand how many and what size groups I want, then I would go creating them one at a time making sure that when I put person A in a group, I immediately make sure he has 2 of his preferences and at each step the group stays gender balanced.

Comment: I doubt I'd have a case where everybody lists the same two people (although some are just naturally popular...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no miracle solution to combinatorial optimisation problems, but you can use "good" heuristics to find a solution :

- local search. You start from an arbitrary solution that check gender constraint.

For example, you create 12 groups of ~38 people with ~19W / ~19M

at each step, you change two people (always 2W or 2M) from 2 sets and you iterate. At the end, you chose the solution that gave you the highest score.

- backtracking

More difficult to implement. You go through the tree of possible sets recursivly and go back when you come to a non-satisfactory solution